# Error when converting datetime to string using dd/MM/yyyy format

Tags: c#, datetime

**My Code :**

This line working properly.

```
txtjoindate.Text = user.Join_Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

And this line giving me error.

```
txtEnddate.Text = user.End_Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

**Error:**

> no overload for method tostring takes 1 arguments

**Edit:**

Here `Join_Date` and `End_Date` are the column names of `userDetails` table which have a  data type `DateTime`.

So please make me understand why it is happening both fields have a same data type still in my first line code it working fine and second line is not working and giving me error as above.

So If somebody have idea about it so please help me.

Comment: What is `Join_Date` and `End_Date` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül Presumably properties of type `DateTime`.

Comment: @StevenLiekens If both were `DateTime` there wouldn't be any error, right? And they can be _field also_. You can't figure out they are _property_ or _field_ looking to `user.Join_Date` without their definition.

Comment: @Govinda can you update your question with the code for the `UserDetails` class?

Comment: @Govinda: thanks for editing, i have removed my downvote. However, are you sure that **both** are `DateTimes`? The accepted answer suggests that one is a `DateTime` and the other is a [`Nullable<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes as I said both Join_Date and End_Date have a same datatype `Datetime`.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar: Then you get no exception. I suspect that you don't know that `DateTime` and `Nullable<DateTime>`(or `DateTime?`) are different types. My last comment contains a link to the documentation of nullables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is `End_Date` nullable (i.e. `DateTime?`)?

Then you should do this:

```
 txtEnddate.Text = user.End_Date.HasValue 
    ? user.End_Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") 
    : "/";
```

EDIT: better handling, tnx to the commenters.

Comment: Better: `user.End_Date != null ? user.End_Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "n/a"`

Comment: If End_Date is nullable, then your code can generate a new exception.

Comment: Note: Accessing `Value` will throw `InvalidOperationException` if not initialized.

Comment: My immediate thought was because it's nullable. Perhaps your code same should include a null check for completeness though. +1

Comment: @marko Juvancic your answer is working but a want to know both field are nullable then why first line is working and second line is not working.please make me understand.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar There is no way to convert (possible) null value to "dd/mm/yyyy". You must handle this case separatly.

Comment: @marko juvancic but my bott fields are `nullable` so I should have got error in my both line code.so why my first line is working fine.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar Maybe add User class declaration to your question.